# why am i getting an error [Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "3"] in line 7 of my code?

Tags: java, runtimeexception

So i was solving a question in competitive programming where i had to take these numbers as input...

```
3 
40 40 100
45 45 90
180 1 1
```

and here's my code:

```
package CP;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException{
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int t=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        while(t-->0){
            StringTokenizer s=new StringTokenizer(br.readLine());
            int a=Integer.parseInt(s.nextToken());
            int b=Integer.parseInt(s.nextToken());
            int c=Integer.parseInt(s.nextToken());
            if(a+b+c==180) System.out.println("YES");
            else System.out.println("NO");
        }
        br.close();
    }
}
```

so this code works fine when i take inputs line by line. but when i take all the lines as input at a time it shows [Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "3"] in line 7. why is this happening?

Comment: Looks like there is an not printable char at the end of the string. BTW Take care of java naming conventions. package names should be lower case

Comment: The question is: what is your input? If your input is from a file, inspect its exact contents using a Hex Editor (like HxD) or some other tool. It may also be related to a Byte Order Mark.

Comment: uhh this is not working in an IDE but when it got accepted when i submitted this code...idk why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a space after the 3 in the input.  This causes the `Integer.parseInt(String)` to fail.  Trimming the line of input should suffice to solve your issue.

```
int t = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine().trim());
```

Comment: ohh yea! thanks a lot